# After adding new event to full calendar, event not rendered

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar

im using fullcalendar jquery plugin in my web.
i have a problem in which after adding a new event to calendar , i have to press some View button in order to render my event to the calendar.

```
var myEvent = {
    title: subject.toString(),
    start: d1,
};

$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', myEvent, true );            
$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
```

suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: trailing comma in object will break IE, is issue cross browser?

Comment: im currently using Chrome, i haven't tried that on other browsers.

Comment: what happens when don't call `renderevents` ? also does the event log to console as valid data for plugin? Are errors thrown??

Comment: see editied comment. Has calendar been initializd also. Post a  link

Comment: Do you have the calendar in a tab or a DIV which is initially hidden from view?

Comment: charliefl i am working with client side only without any console log.
@ganeshk the div isn't hidden but the div is inside another div which hidden until you redirected to it.

Comment: @ganeshk i ran a test and your right about the hidden idea.
but, is there any way to have a hidden div and still use this functionality?

Comment: Cool - try adding the renderEvent/rerenderEvents inside the call that shows the parent DIV. That might solve your issue.

Comment: its ok now, write is an answer so i can accept it :) Thank you very much

Comment: @ganeshk open an answer so i can mark V :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have the calendar in a hidden DIV. If you add the render/rerender calls to the function that shows/unhides this DIV, then the events should render correctly.

Comment: that is a question, not answer. Use comments for questions and please delete answer. It provides no value to anyone